Removing trailing slashes in nginx-unit
Is there any way to remove trailing slashes in nginx-unit config?
In nginx I have the following:
    if ($request_uri ~* "^(.+)/$") {
        return 301 $scheme://$http_host$1;
    }


But it's hard for me to convert it to nginx-unit format. Is there any idea?
I've tried options like
  {
      "match": {
          "uri": [
              "/.*\\/$"
          ]
      },
  
      "action": {
          "rewrite": "/$1",
          "pass": "applications/php/index"
      }
  },

but with no success
